# How to exit gnuplot when any command in the input script fails?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to script gnuplot to output a png.

I rely on the user to give me the output filename. If the user enters an invalid filename, gnuplot ends up printing png to stdout. Terminals usually don't like this kind of stress. At times even `reset` is not able to bring my shell back.

Is there a way to abort all processing if any command goes wrong ? I'd be looking for a global error variable (a la `errno`) or a global error event I could assign a function to.

Alternatively, is there a way to abort processing testing for the result of the former command (a bit like `if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then`).

Finally, if that's the only option, just detect that my `set terminal` failed and fallback to something else not stdout.

Obviously I'll try and "touch" the output to verify it's writable, but I'd like a more general solution.

Comment: Have you considered making your script validate the filename before handing it off to gnuplot?

Comment: Yes, I'll be doing this ... but that doesn't protect me from other input errors. Imagine I'd want the user to configure the line style, that would take quite a lot of effort to validate (though less harmfull).

Comment: You could also redirect gnuplot's `stdout` to `/dev/null`, or else through a filter that cleans it up.

Comment: I've checked the docs and it looks like errors are printed to `stderr` - that makes the `/dev/null` pretty attractive indeed.

Comment: As far as I can tell, gnuplot has no analog of `errno` and `$?`, but I am not confident enough in that assessment to make an answer of it.

Comment: I was answering with `if (GPVAL_ERRNO==1) exit` but it seems there is a bug: after `set output '/blabla/'` (which throws an error) `GPVAL_ERRNO` is still `0` which should not happen (`help gnuplot-defined variables`)

Comment: @bibi This has been reported on the gnuplot bug tracker as bug [#1741](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1741/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If gnuplot encounters an error, it will be stored in the variables `GPVAL_ERRNO` (the error number - default is 0) and `GPVAL_ERRMSG` (the error message - default is `""`).

Therefore, you can test for an error in your script:

```
if (GPVAL_ERRNO != 0) exit
```

---

As, bibi mentioned in the comments, when setting your output to an invalid file, an error will be thrown but will not set these values (I suspect that the error occurs somewhere "deeper" than the gnuplot interpreter is why).  As far as I know, this is the only time that this wouldn't be set.

However, there are also varibles which store the terminal settings: `GPVAL_TERM` (the current terminal), `GPVAL_TERMOPTIONS` (the current options for the terminal), and `GPVAL_OUTPUT` (the current output file).

For example, if I issue `set term png` followed by `set output "test.png"`, the values are `"png"`, `"nocrop enhanced size 640,480 font \"arial,12\" "`, and `"test.png"` respectively.

When the output is set to **STDOUT**, the value of `GPVAL_OUTPUT` is `""` (the empty string).  So we can test for the empty string to determine if we were able to set the output file name.

```
set output some_invalid_file
if (GPVAL_OUTPUT == "") exit
```

Gnuplot's if command does allow bracketed expressions for bodies with more than one line, so we could print a warning to the user as well:

```
if (GPVAL_OUTPUT = "") {
    print "Stop giving invalid file names!!!"
    exit
}
```

---

**Notice:** The problem mentioned with *set output* not setting the error code has been reported as a bug in the gnuplot source as [bug number 1741](https://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/bugs/1741/) and a fix has been added to the current development version.